# Appcenter notification Management (view/hide functionality for certain users)

Tags: visual-studio-app-center

Not sure where to post this questions.

Is there a "Role" I can define in appcenter so that only certain people can "see/send" push notification or view analitcs etc..

Can I associate different emails to a single appcenter account and give them different role of what they can see or do?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

App Center allows you to define permissions for different users and teams, this is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/dashboard/creating-and-managing-teams#changing-permissions. Unfortunately, there's no permission that enables you to hide services or capabilities.